# Groovy's JsonSlurper: is it thread safe?

Tags: java, groovy, thread-safety

Is Groovy's JsonSlurper thread safe?

In other words, can a single instance of JsonSlurper be used across multple threads to parseText(), or should each thread create its own instance of JsonSlurper?

Comment: Why not just create a new instance when you need it? Forgive my ignorance, I've never used it.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6934 may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.java#L91) JsonSlurper creates a new parser object whenever you call a `parse*` ([1](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.java#L201), [2](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.java#L214), [3](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.java#L232) etc) method.

There is minimal state with the JsonSlurper ([an int, 3 booleans and an enum value](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.java#L93)); it's not technically thread-safe, as you don't have a guarantee that any changes to these fields are visible between threads.

However, because there is minimal state, it doesn't seem worth worrying about reusing instances. Just create one whenever you need it.